# How do i find and restore a sidebar that i accidentally deleted?

Tags: loop

How to i restore a sidebar that i accidentally deleted? This is the link to my site. Also how to i remove the footer designed by wordpress?
http://ngomanager.org/about/

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with 'deleted' ? Did you empty all the entries from the sidebar widget…?

Answer (score 1):

If you removed widgets from your sidebar, the only way to restore them would be to restore your database from a backup before they were deleted. Some hosts provide backup options (even after the fact) particularly if you pay a little extra for the service. WP stores widgets in the database and when they're edited it doesn't store a backup.

If you can't recover them that way, you could try checking [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) or Google's Cache (depending on how long ago you deleted things) to see visually what they looked like before. You could then rebuild them.